# TargetFrameworks does not work on VS 2019 16.6.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to compile a binary for net35 and net40 simultaneously, something similar to [Newtonsoft.Json.csproj](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj#L3)

So I created a `.NET Console project` with `VS 2019 16.6.2`. Then I closed VS and edited the csproj file manually,

1. Replaced `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` with `<TargetFrameworks>net35;net40</TargetFrameworks>`
2. Replaced `<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">` with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`

Then I reopened Visual Studio and recompile the solution, it still generates `test -> C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\test\test\bin\Debug\test.exe`

I was expecting two separate folder, aka `net35\test.exe` and `net40\test.exe`

What did I miss?

Comment: You should use SDK-style project for that, not the old msbuild-style project, which `TargetFrameworkVersion` property belongs to

Comment: Because your changes do not touch the output directory at all, so you should expect nothing changes. If you really want a good console project to get started with, use `dotnet new console` to create one.

Comment: Did you do any other changes to your `xxx.csproj`? For me, I suggest follow your step and it can output the files into `net35\test.exe` and `net40\test.exe`? Did you set any other values to `outoutpath` property? Did you built this project without any errors?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I've recreated a project with `dotnet new console` command and it worked. Project created with visual studio will not work.

Comment: @daisy, the reason is that you created a net framework project rather than a net core console project previously. To use the new sdk style's outputpath, you should created a net core console project and then change to use `<TargetFrameworks>net35;net40</TargetFrameworks>` and then you will see the results as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TargetFrameworks does not work on VS 2019 16.6.2

**Actually**, that is not an issue of Visual Studio.

The reason is that you first created an old-sdk style project(**Net Framework** project), the old-sdk style cannot get the new sdk's **outputpath**(what you want is the new sdk's outputpath-----**Net Core** or **Net Standard**) and if you migrate the old-sdk style into the new-sdk style, you might get into some trouble. And We also do not recommend you to do this.

**So for your situation**, you could first create a **Net Core** Console Application in **Visual Studio** rather than  a**Net Framework** project.

**Suggestion**

I suggest you could create a **Net Core Console** project in visual studio or use `dotnet new console` by `dotnet.exe`, then you can modify the new project, use this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net35;net40</TargetFrameworks>
```

Then you can see what you expected in the outputpath.

[image]